# How to read IP Address on my mobile when using Nativescript

Tags: android, angular, typescript, mobile, ip

In my project, I need to create a function that receives the IP address of the phone it uses. My question is how? I didn't work for this before, and I'm not finding any information to help me. Please, can you give me any idea how to do this? What library / plugin can I use to read IP address of my phone?

```
import * as application from 'application';
import { android } from "application";
var context = application.android.context;
var  wifiMgr = context.getSystemService("wifi");
var wifiInfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();
var ip = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
console.log('android.context',android.context)
var  ipAddress = android.context.format.Formatter.formatIpAddress(ip);
```

Show Formatter Undefined

Answer (score 0):

For get Wifi Ip address you can use this code:

```
WifiManager wManager = (WifiManager) 
getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
String ipAddress =Formatter.formatIpAddress(wManager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
```

Comment: Can you see my Update please?